# test if a MatrixBase is a fixed size or dynamic in Eigen3

Tags: c++, eigen3

Hopefully this is an easy one and I'm just failing at google today....but.

Given

```
MatrixBase<double> &mat
```

is there a way to test if mat is fixed or dynamic size?

I don't think this will work:

```
mat.rows() == Dynamic
```

I was hoping for something like:

```
mat.dynamic_rows (true or false)
mat.dynamic_cols (true or false)
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve] yuo can start from this example: https://godbolt.org/z/GE5Ers7vK

Comment: Also do you want to check this on runtime or compile time? What is actual problem since this sounds like [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html you can look at TheMatrixType::RowsAtCompileTime and see if it is Dynamic.

Comment: @MarekR you're on the money. This is what I was trying to do: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.